# Form Input Element Not Working

Tags: forms, jsp

I am making a small JSP page with a form in it. However, the "Full Name" text input field is not allowing me to type text into it? Does anyone know what the cause of the problem is? The code for my JSP page is below.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Billing Workflow Tracker</title>
<style>
    #formTitle {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;}
    #formPart1 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 1s;}
    #formPart2 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;}
    #buttonPart1 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 180px;}
    #buttonPart2 {position: absolute; 
    left: 70px;
    top: 180px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function showFormPart1()
        {
            document.getElementById("formPart1").style.opacity = 1;
            document.getElementById("formPart2").style.opacity = 0;
        }

        function showFormPart2()
        {
            document.getElementById("formPart1").style.opacity = 0;
            document.getElementById("formPart2").style.opacity = 1;
        }
    </script>
    <h1 id="formTitle">Billing Workflow Tracker</h1>
    <form id="formPart1">
        <label>Full Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></label>
        <label>E-mail <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></label>
    </form>
    <form id="formPart2"> 
        <p>Reason for Billing Test</p>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason1" value="1" />
        <label for="reason1">New Customer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason2" value="2" />
        <label for="reason2">Migration</label>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason3" value="3" />
        <label for="reason3">Other</label>
    </form>
    <button id="buttonPart1" onclick="showFormPart1()">Part 1</button>
    <button id="buttonPart2" onclick="showFormPart2()">Part 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by also changing the display property when I change the opacity.

Answer (score 0):

How about using "display" instead of "opacity"?
For example:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Billing Workflow Tracker</title>
<style>
    #formTitle {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;}
    #formPart1 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    display: block;}
    #formPart2 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    display: none;}
    #buttonPart1 {position: absolute; 
    left: 10px;
    top: 180px;}
    #buttonPart2 {position: absolute; 
    left: 70px;
    top: 180px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function showFormPart1()
        {
            document.getElementById("formPart1").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("formPart2").style.display = "none";
        }

        function showFormPart2()
        {
            document.getElementById("formPart1").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("formPart2").style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
    <h1 id="formTitle">Billing Workflow Tracker</h1>
    <form id="formPart1">
        <label>Full Name <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></label>
        <label>E-mail <input type="email" name="email" id="email" /></label>
    </form>
    <form id="formPart2"> 
        <p>Reason for Billing Test</p>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason1" value="1" />
        <label for="reason1">New Customer</label>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason2" value="2" />
        <label for="reason2">Migration</label>
        <input type="radio" name="reasons" id="reason3" value="3" />
        <label for="reason3">Other</label>
    </form>
    <button id="buttonPart1" onclick="showFormPart1()">Part 1</button>
    <button id="buttonPart2" onclick="showFormPart2()">Part 2</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The cause is that `formPart2` is transparent but it is on `formPart1` and blocks user input.